# Webfont rendering issue in Chromium browsers

Tags: windows, fonts, chromium, rendering

My computer is running Windows 10 and for the last months I have encountered a problem I can't quite get hold of. In Chromium browsers (Chrome, Opera, Edge) some websites using webfonts get rendered wrong. For example the following site looks as intended in Firefox, but wrong in Chrome or any other Chromium browser: https://lbv.landbw.de/kundenportal

**Chromium browsers rendering some weird pixel font**

[image: Chromium browsers rendering some weird pixel font]

vs. **Firefox rendering as intended**

[image: Firefox rendering as intended]

I first thought it was some AdBlocker going rogue, but even with all extensions disabled the webfont doesn't load correctly. I then inspected the Network tab of DevTools and for some reason, the webfont isn't even trying to load anything although the @font-face declaration lists several valid options. It doesn't seem to be a network issue as on other devices in the same network the fonts load all right.

This happens on a lot of websites. I chose this one for an example because it has a working webfont and one which isn't working. I can't figure out what is going on here. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I am confused, WebKit is Safari, not Chromium (Blink) based.

Comment: That's my fault then. I changed the question and tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution. The reason for the faulty rendering was an error in the `@font-face` selection by Chromium due to an faulty font installed on my system. The declaration of the font source started with an empty `local("")` declaration:

```
src: local(""),url(…
```

The intention of this seems to always choose the provided webfonts instead of a local font. But this failed in my case. In the *Computed* styles section of dev tools I could see that instead some random local font was selected instead:

[image: Random font selected by Chromium]

This was most likely an error by the font creator who failed to set its font name table values correctly. I uninstalled the font in question and after a browser restart the correct webfont was loaded.